# What's the purpose of the "base" (for best practices) in Anaconda?

Tags: anaconda, conda

It says it's a default environment but "You don't want to put programs into your base environment, though"

So what exactly should I use it for? Do other environments I create inherit from the base?

Comment: Where do you see that advice?

Comment: @darthbith https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html

Comment: Nice to see that the Conda devs are endorsing a minimal **base** practice. I strongly encourage this as it seems to be the most stable long term and minimizes Conda having to solve overcomplicated dependency graphs. Now, if only Anaconda stopped shipping with everything installed in **base**....

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The base environment is where `conda` itself gets installed. It's best to use Miniconda, and install *all* the things you want into separate environments.

Other environments do not inherit packages from the base environment. BUT the `bin/` directory of the base environment is in the search path for executables. So if you call `conda` from inside any of your environments (which usually don't have conda installed), the one from the base environment is used.

If you install other executables into the base environment, they can be called from your other environments. But you'll have a hell of a tough time to distinguish whether the things you can call are actually in your environment, or in the base environment.
Therefore, it's best to just have `conda` in the base environment. And maybe other generic tools, like `git` or `make`, if you install that kind of tool with conda. But packages that are imported by your Python/R/whatever code do not belong into the base environment.

Don't worry about disk space if you create multiple environments with the same packages. `conda` does a very good job with hard-linking the same packages into multiple environments to save space.

The full Anaconda installer puts a ton of stuff into the base environment. That might seem convenient at first, but when you start creating new environments, you'll run into the problem I mentioned. You can call stuff from your new environment although it isn't installed there. Using Miniconda avoids this, at the cost of having to create a new environment before actually being able to use stuff. However, there's an anaconda meta-package which you can install to get the "ton of stuff" with one command.

Comment: In more recent versions of conda, `conda` is a bash function, not a specific executable (although I believe the executable remains for backwards compatibility).

Comment: Also: anything one installs in any environment is shared through hardlinks, so there really is no reason to favor installing something in **base** for "inheritance" purposes. The only advantage to installing in **base** is that you can have tools immediately available on shell initialization if you allow auto-activation. Personally, I still install `git`, `jupyter`, and some domain-specific command line tools that I use daily for that convenience.

Comment: @merv Thanks, I've updated the answer. I never got the idea of installing git through Anaconda rather than the Linux package manager :-)

Comment: @darthbith I think the conda bash function calls the executable for heavy-lifting stuff like "conda install". The function is a facade to unify the conda executable, "source activate", "source deactivate", and maybe some more. `conda` still needs to work on systems without bash, so they'll keep the scripts around.

Comment: @RolandWeber On a cluster where you don't have admin privileges, Conda can essentially be your local package manager.

Comment: @RolandWeber Yes, that seems correct. Interesting, I wonder why they added the shell function redirection at all...

Comment: But that doesn't explain why they switched to a shell function, instead of just relying on `conda` being on the `PATH`. I guess except maybe that its faster, since everything stays in the shell? But I don't think it does...

Comment: @darthbith They switched to a shell function so they can use `conda activate` everywhere, instead of `source activate` in bash and who-knows-what on Windows.

Comment: But if `conda` (the executable) is on the `PATH`, you could still use `conda activate`, as in, `conda` is the name of the executable and `activate` is the first argument.

Comment: @RolandWeber Anyways, I don't expect to find an answer it was more idle curiosity :-)

Comment: @darthbith `activate` cannot be implemented as a command. It needs to modify the environment of the current shell, whereas commands are executed in a subshell or run as a separate process. `activate` must either be called with `source`, or it must be a shell function or alias.

Comment: @RolandWeber That's the explanation. Thank you!