# Facing issue with installation of witwidget (google what-if too) on Windows in Anaconda

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I am facing issue with installation of What-If tool.

`pip install tensorflow` completed successfully.

`pip install witwidget` completed successfully.

`jupyter nbextension install --py --symlink --sys-prefix witwidget` failed with the error below)

- **Environment:** Windows 10
- **Python version:** 3.7.0

```
(base) C:\Users\ankitagarwal5>jupyter nbextension install --py --symlink --sys-prefix witwidget
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ankitagarwal5\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\ankitagarwal5\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\ankitagarwal5\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\ankitagarwal5\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\ankitagarwal5\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ankitagarwal5\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-nbextension-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\ankitagarwal5\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\application.py", line 266, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ankitagarwal5\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "C:\Users\ankitagarwal5\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\nbextensions.py", line 988, in start
    super(NBExtensionApp, self).start()
  File "C:\Users\ankitagarwal5\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\application.py", line 255, in start
    self.subapp.start()
  File "C:\Users\ankitagarwal5\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\nbextensions.py", line 716, in start
    self.install_extensions()
  File "C:\Users\ankitagarwal5\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\nbextensions.py", line 695, in install_extensions
    **kwargs
  File "C:\Users\ankitagarwal5\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\nbextensions.py", line 211, in install_nbextension_python
    m, nbexts = _get_nbextension_metadata(module)
  File "C:\Users\ankitagarwal5\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\nbextensions.py", line 1122, in _get_nbextension_metadata
    m = import_item(module)
  File "C:\Users\ankitagarwal5\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\utils\importstring.py", line 42, in import_item
    return __import__(parts[0])
  File "C:\Users\ankitagarwal5\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\witwidget\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from witwidget.notebook.visualization import *
  File "C:\Users\ankitagarwal5\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\witwidget\notebook\visualization.py", line 17, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\ankitagarwal5\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 101, in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "C:\Users\ankitagarwal5\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\ankitagarwal5\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\Users\ankitagarwal5\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\Users\ankitagarwal5\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\ankitagarwal5\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\ankitagarwal5\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ankitagarwal5\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\ankitagarwal5\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\ankitagarwal5\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\ankitagarwal5\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\ankitagarwal5\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Comment: Practically speaking, you shouldn't be working with the base environment. Have you tried creating a virtual environment to install packages?

Comment: I have not created the virtual environment. I was trying it on base environment. If I create virtual envirnoment, would I be able to use that through Jupyter Anaconda?

Comment: If you install Jupyter in the virtual environment, yes.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to ask, are you using Miniconda or Anaconda? If using Anaconda, it installs everything in the base environment. Personally, I use Miniconda and install everything in virtual environments with a very minimal base environment. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56504279/ Also check out https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22794 You may need to install the MSVC redistributable.

Comment: I am using Anaconda so wondering why still getting this error when everything is installed in base environment. Any suggestions on correcting this issue while continuing with base Anaconda environment?

Comment: Did you check the GitHub issue and the comments about installing the MSVC redistributable?

Comment: We would not need MSVC if we downgrade to tensorflow 2.0 and 2.1 onwards we need MSVC for GPU compatibility

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in the GitHub issue I linked. There is no reason to avoid installing the MSVC redistributable though, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue and it seems it was primarily due to tensorflow version. Well here are the steps I followed to install witwidget on my Windows laptop with Anaconda Python (v3.7)

pip install pyhamcrest
pip install google-auth
conda update wrapt

### Now is the important part. You need to uninstall tensorflow, if it is version > 2.0. So try running this command to install tensorflow v 2.0

pip install tensorflow==2.0.0

## Then execute these commands and you are good to go

pip install witwidget
jupyter nbextension install --py --symlink --sys-prefix witwidget
jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix witwidget

Thanks !